# getapplicatiocontext or getbasecontext on main activity

Tags: android

It is not working when i call this

```
 AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getBaseContext()).create();
 // Setting Dialog Title
 alertDialog.setTitle(e.getMessage());
 alertDialog.show();
```

In `MainActivity`, how to get it working?

The stacktrace is:

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not 
        for an application 03-18 16:38:07.505: 
 E/AndroidRuntime(13152): at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:540) 03-18 16:38:07.505: 
 E/AndroidRuntime(13152): at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:259) –
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are in a class that extends `Activity` you could use

```
  AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
   // Setting Dialog Title
  alertDialog.setTitle(e.getMessage());
  if(!mActivity.this.isFinishing()) {
        alertDialog.show();
  }
```